# Show undocumented function parameters

Tags: doxygen

I'm using doxygen for generating HTML documentation of a C++ code. Unfortunately doxygen doesn't show undocumented method parameters in the method description. For example, with the following

```
/**
 * Some method
 * @param p1 Some param
 */
void method(const std::string& p1, const std::string& p2);
```

the method description will show the comment and the parameter `p1` but not `p2`.

How can I configure doxygen to list all parameters in the method description even if not explicitly documented?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible (I may be wrong). The parameter `p2` appears in the method signature in the doxygen documentation, is this not sufficient? If you want it to also appear in the list of parameters I think you will have to document it (you could leave the documentation blank, e.g. use just `\param p2`).

Comment: It looks to me more consistent when all parameters are listed and the undocumented ones have a blank comment (like in the JavaDoc). Documenting all parameters would of course solve this problem but then I could directly write a comment. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

Doxygen can warn you about incomplete, wrong, or missing parameter documentation though.

The relevant settings are:

```
WARNINGS          = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC  = YES
```